# how to loop through the contentful data within javascript and display in bootstrap grid columns?

Tags: javascript, html, contentful

I'm working on the Contentful CMS for posting some data and retrieving it in an html page. I use JavaScript to display those in bootstrap grid columns, but it not showing the data properly.

here is my code:

```
     <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div id="content"></div>
       </div>

      var client = contentful.createClient({
      space: '#######',
       accessToken: '#######'
     })

 var container = document.querySelector('#content');

  client.getEntries()
  .then(function(entries) {
    container.innerHTML = renderProducts(entries.items)
  })


function renderProducts(products) {
    products.map(function(product) {
        console.log(product.fields)
        return  '<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">' +
            '<a href="service-details.html" class="single-feature wow fadeInUp">' +
                '<img src="assets/images/icon/064-vector.png" alt="">' +
                '<div class="content">' +
                    '<h4 class="title">' +
                        '<p>cool</p>' +
                    '</h4>'+ 
                '</div>' +
            '</a>' +
      '</div>'
  })
}
```

It showing the data in console properly, but the HTML is not rendering the way I want.

Answer (score 0):

Heyo. I didn't test I could see two potential issues. `renderProducts` is not returning anything. You could try changing it to return your mapped `products`. And then `innerHTML` expects a string value, which means that you'd have to join your mapped array together.

```
function renderProducts(products) {
    //add a return here
    return products.map(function(product) {
        console.log(product.fields)
        return  '<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">' +
            '<a href="service-details.html" class="single-feature wow fadeInUp">' +
                '<img src="assets/images/icon/064-vector.png" alt="">' +
                '<div class="content">' +
                    '<h4 class="title">' +
                        '<p>cool</p>' +
                    '</h4>'+ 
                '</div>' +
            '</a>' +
      '</div>'
  }).join('');
  //  join the array of strings together to one long string
}
```